# Get access of object in LayoutInflater Android Java

Tags: java, android

How to access palette in layout that inflated to AlertDialog such as Radio Button, Button, TextEdit and more.

Coz i use Layout to AlertDialog and  tried this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(LocateMe.this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(LocateMe.this);
View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
RadioGroup rgSetMap = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rgSetMap);
int idRB = rgSetMap.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
final RadioButton rbSet = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(idRB);

alertadd.setView(view);
alertadd.setTitle("Map View Setting");
alertadd.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
         Log.d("SET", rbSet.getText().toString());
      }
});

alertadd.show();
```

But it wont work.

heres Layout XML

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgSetMap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Normal"
        android:id="@+id/rbNormal"
        android:padding="20dp"

        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hybrid"
        android:id="@+id/rbHybrid"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Satellite"
        android:id="@+id/rbSat"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Terrain"
        android:id="@+id/rbTer"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
</RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what i wanted to access

```
RadioGroup rgSetMap = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rgSetMap);
    int idRB = rgSetMap.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    final RadioButton rbSet = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(idRB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code to this. Find your view from alertadd dialog not from view. Thatswhy it is returning null.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(LocateMe.this);
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(LocateMe.this);
        View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
        alertadd.setView(view);

        final RadioGroup rgSetMap = (RadioGroup) alertadd.findViewById(R.id.rgSetMap);
        final int idRB = rgSetMap.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        alertadd.setTitle("Map View Setting");
        alertadd.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                View radioButton = rgSetMap.findViewById(idRB);
                int radioId = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg1.getChildAt(radioId);
                String selection = (String) btn.getText();
            }
        });

        alertadd.show();
```